# is this a universal error of all the programming languages

Tags: python, c++

i am facing this problem in python below is the code in python

```
>>> p=350.
>>> p-=0.1
>>> p-=0.1
>>> print p-349.8
-5.68434188608e-14
>>>
```

i have checked this program many times and i think the output of `print p-349.8`
should have come 0.
i have also tried this in other languages too in c++ , Java and python
and i want output to come 0.0
please help

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Floating point is the same everywhere. However, your particular interaction would result in `0.0` in e.g. Lisp or Racket, because they treat literals such as `0.1` exactly (i.e. not as floating point) unless you tell them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all programming languages deal in base-2 numbers and therefore it is difficult to accurately express a floating point number as a base-10.

You could perhaps use the [**`Decimal`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) Class

Comment: An alternative - if you know in advance how many decimal places you are going to be using (e.g. in financial applications) - is to multiply out the decimal places and do the Math with Ints. e.g. in finance work in pennies as opposed to pounds.

Comment: Some (admittedly obscure) language use rationals or decimal floating point by default. Those don't exhibit these specific errors (though they have other limitations).